# Win32 Compiler errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I managed to get a code from the net for PC to a machine communication via RS-232.
I'm using Win32 Console Application in VS2010.
I wanted to run it and see the outcome.
But I have some errors which I am unable to rectify.

Heres's the code:

```
    // HTHH.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "windows.h"

    HANDLE hSerial;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        hSerial = CreateFile("COM4",  
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                0, 
                0, 
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                0);
        if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        }

        }

        DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};

        dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

        if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
        {
        }
            dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
            dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

        if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParam))
{
}
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
    {
    }

        char szbuff[n+1] = {0};
        DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

        if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szbuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
        {

     CloseHandle(hSerial);

    return 0;
   }
```

The errors are as follows:--

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(17): error C2664: 'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'

1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(28): error C2065: 'dcbSerial' : undeclared identifier

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(28): error C2228: left of '.DCBlength' must have class/struct/union

1>          type is ''unknown-type''

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(38): error C2065: 'dcbSerialParam' : undeclared identifier

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(53): error C2065: 'n' : undeclared identifier

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(56): error C2065: 'n' : undeclared identifier

1>c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(64): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' 
at 'c:\users\singanathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\hthh\hthh\hthh.cpp(10)' was matched
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Sorry, its very lenghty.
Appreciate your advise.

Thanks

Comment: First step would probably be to turn off `Unicode` from the code generation of your project. That will get rid of the error from `"COM4:"` being a `const char [5]` which is not compatible with `const wchar_t *` (aka `LPCWSTR`. The other errors are simple typos, so should just require looking at the line and fixing up what the problem is.

Comment: Also Serial communication is not trivial... I suggest to use a read-to-use library, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C

Comment: @Jochen: I find that the Win32 API is more ready-to-use than most wrappers.

Comment: @Ben: Most wrappers use the Win32 API ;) ... For beginners: Good wrappers are better then finding out by yourself, what you need to know in order to **read** data from the port... from my Point of view, this is not trival.

Comment: @Jochen: Most wrappers try to hide the Win32 API, which is exceptionally well-designed, behind a facade designed by amateurs.  For example, in the library you linked, there is a claim that Win32 serial I/O functions don't support an event driven callback model.  That's false, one is already provided in `ReadFileEx`.  I've used the separate-thread-for-I/O model to implement serial ports in .NET because you don't control the message loop.  In normal Win32-via-C++ programming that isn't necessary, you can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` in your event loop and have I/O callbacks.

Comment: @Ben: The linked library has 4 different programming models for Serial ports... there is also an event driven approach... also, for beginners it is easier to use a well-tested library than to elaborate the usage by himself... if you are an expert, you might want to have more control, thats true. I still suggest for beginners to use a well-tested library.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling targeting `UNICODE` and so `CreateFile` maps to `CreateFileW` which expects wide character arrays, `wchar_t*`. But `"COM4"` is a `char` literal. Change it to `L"COM4"`.

The compiler told you that `dcbSerial` is undeclared. It's right. And same for `dcbSerialParam`. The variable you declared is named `dcbSerialParams`.

And you did not declare `n` at all.